# panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference in golang

Tags: go

I run this code in my mac. I test it and it is ok. But i compile it and start it at aws ecs. I get this error

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x10 pc=0x55fff8]

goroutine 6 [running]:

go.sia.tech/siad/types.NewCurrency(0xc0000d5640)

/Users/jaslin.wang/go/pkg/mod/go.sia.tech/siad@v1.5.8/types/currency.go:57 +0x18
```

There is my code. It get error when call this line 80

```
74 amount, _ := new(big.Int).SetString(output.Value, 10)
75
76 addr := types.UnlockHash{}
77 addr.LoadString(output.Address)
78
79 sco := types.SiacoinOutput{
80   Value:      types.NewCurrency(amount),
81   UnlockHash: addr,
82 }
```

The `NewCurrency` function is

```
56 func NewCurrency(b *big.Int) (c Currency) {
57   if b.Sign() < 0 {
58     build.Critical(ErrNegativeCurrency)
59   } else {
60     c.i = *b
61   }
62   return
63 }
```

There is my compile command

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: Did `new(big.Int).SetString(output.Value, 10)` return `nil, false`?

Comment: In my mac, it return correct value. I will add if statement to check this

Comment: @CeriseLimón, it's interesting, that the argument to `NewCurrency` in the stack trace is not 0x00 but rather 0xc0000d5640, wich, on Intel/ARM should not mean `nil` pointer. Still, the `Sign` method might access something unexpectedly `nil` in the receiver's value. Just guessing, of course.

Comment: don't think so, @karora - returns an `int` (https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Int.Sign)

Comment: `b` is nil.  The implementation of `sign` doesn't dereference anything else.

Answer (score 0):

```
2022/08/30 03:30:05 output.Value is 340900000000000000000000000.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

2022-08-30T11:30:05.726+08:00   2022/08/30 03:30:05 ok is false

2022-08-30T11:30:05.726+08:00   2022/08/30 03:30:05 amount is <nil>
```

sry to bother you guys. I don't know why `output.Value` is `340900000000000000000000000.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`. It should be `340900000000000000000000000`. But i think change it to `340900000000000000000000000` will fix this issue. Thank all of you!

Comment: Do post this as an edition to the original question, I don't think this applies as a valid answer in itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether big.SetString() actually parsed the value.  Try running this code to see it happen...  Presumably SetString() is not parsing your value because you're using a big.Int() and passing it a string with floating point decimals (even if they are zeroes).

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

type Currency struct {
    i big.Int
}

func main() {
    for _, v := range []string{"1234567878768376294872638", "boom!"} {
        amount, ok := new(big.Int).SetString(v, 10)
        if !ok {
            fmt.Println("Expecting this will go boom!")
        }
        x := NewCurrency(amount)
        fmt.Println(x)
    }
}

func NewCurrency(b *big.Int) (c Currency) {
    if b.Sign() < 0 {
        fmt.Printf("Error negative currency")
        panic("panicking!")
    } else {
        c.i = *b
    }
    return
}
```